# Shell command for getting mac address in OS X

Tags: macos, shell, mac-address

I have been handicapped by the GUI and always seem to ask of help when it comes to the command line.

On Mac OS X only I need a command line to get the mac address of the wifi currently in use.

Help!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think the best and easiest way to get the information is using this command:

```
networksetup -listallhardwareports
```

It will return a nice list of devices like this:

```
Hardware Port: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
Device: en6
Ethernet Address: 00:e0:4c:...

Hardware Port: Wi-Fi
Device: en0
Ethernet Address: 80:e6:50:...

Hardware Port: Bluetooth PAN
Device: en3
Ethernet Address: 80:e6:50:...

Hardware Port: Thunderbolt 1
Device: en1
Ethernet Address: 72:00:05:...

Hardware Port: Thunderbolt 2
Device: en2
Ethernet Address: 72:00:05:...

Hardware Port: Thunderbolt Bridge
Device: bridge0
Ethernet Address: 72:00:05:...

VLAN Configurations
===================
```

Comment: This command seems to always give you initial mac address. I changed it via `ifconfig ...` and `networksetup ...` still shows initial address not actual one.

Answer (score 57):

ifconfig en1 gets the interface details for wifi, the mac is on a line starting with ether, and is the second word on that line so:

```
ifconfig en1 | awk '/ether/{print $2}'
```

Comment: `awk` and `grep`? Why not just `ifconfig en1 | awk '/ether/{print $2}'`

Comment: How to know the WiFi interface index for sure? It seems like it's `en0` for some people so your code would fail

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza `networksetup -listallhardwareports` (see jarsever's answer)

Comment: For macbooks it's normally en0 these days, as per another answer `ifconfig en0 | awk '/ether/{print $2}'`

Comment: This is wrong, if your are on VPN and have additional CONX, you won't be able to get the right MAC address. I posted a solution that chooses the right Address below.

Comment: en1 interface doesnot always belongs to Wi-Fi. In my Mac, en1 interface belongs to Thunderbolt port 2 and en0 interface belongs to Wi-Fi

Answer (score 12):

```
networksetup -getmacaddress <interface>
```

Comment: It may be better to use this command:
`networksetup -listallhardwareports`

Comment: This command seems to always give you initial mac address. I changed it via `ifconfig ...` and `networksetup ...` still shows initial address not actual one.

Answer (score 8):

This will easily give you the specific Mac Address for your Wifi Interface

```
networksetup -listallhardwareports | grep Wi-Fi -A 3 | awk '/Ethernet Address:/{print $3}'
```

Comment: this is the correct answer as it's not predicated on knowing the interface.

Comment: heh, I was just about to post this exact `grep -A`-based approach. Nice.

Answer (score 7):

Wifi mac address is normally can be found in en0. So you may try this command on Terminal

```
ifconfig en0 | awk '/ether/{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 5):

`ifconfig` should do the trick, it'll display a bunch of info including your MAC address. Alternatively it'll be in your network settings under system preferences.

**EDIT**

On a computer with just a wireless connection, en0 will have your wifi settings. The tag labeled with ether will most likely be your MAC address.

If you have both a wired and wireless connection, it'll be under ether in the en1 tag

Source: http://m.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=30929